# how to execute .exe file run as administrator after installing installer with java nsis script

Tags: java, nsis

After installing my installer .exe file run with right button click and the run as administration i want it with double click and by default run as administrator.Thanks.

Comment: How is the NSIS tag relevant here?

Comment: It's relevant with NSIS cause i want to make an installer which fulfills the above criteria of my query.

Comment: Can you clarify if it is just the installer that needs to run your application as administrator or does your application always need to run as administrator?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about an actual .exe file to be "always run as administrator" on double click or just on simply click open/run option but what you do the following:

1. Create a Start Menu shortcut
2. Right click on shortcut and click "Open file location"
3. It will open a folder, something named like "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\"
4. Right click on the shortcut file and click "Properties"
5. On the shortcut tab, click "Advanced" and check the option "Run as administrator".

[image: Run as administrator]

Comment: This property is something a user can set, applications should not set it on their own shortcuts. Application authors should fix their application instead.